# Unknown ANSI escape sequence

Tags: unix, terminal, ascii, ansi-escape

I'm trying to create a HTML terminal emulator. With most of the formatting code I'm OK, [pages like this](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences-vt-100.php) are a great help. However the line containing the prompt is strange (string, then the ASCII codes below):

```
\e]0;pi@igor: ~{??}\e[01;32mpi@igor:[01;34m~ $  
####
27 93 48 59 112 105 64 105 103 111 114 58 32 126 7 27 91 48 49 59 51 50 109 112 105 64 105 103 111 114 27 91 48 48 109 58 27 91
```

First of all, at the beginning of the line there's this \e] (Esc + closing bracket!) sequence I don't see in the docs. With an opening bracket it would be better, but even that I can't find in the reference.

The next thing is that char code 7 that I replaced with {??} in the string.  Right after the prompt there's a single byte 7.

The actual prompt here is

```
pi@igor:~ $
```

with formatting (and igor is a Raspberry Pi), so the string is perfectly fine (even if truncated by me) after the {??} part, i.e. char 7. But what is it before that?

Edit: so yes, char 7 would be the bell in ASCII. If it's that, why does it have the full prompt go with it?

Comment: This is an _xterm_ defined sequence, not ANSI _or_ DEC. See https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Operating-System-Commands (and the top of the page where OSC is explained as ESC ] _or_ \x9D).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is setting the terminal title to `pi@igor: ~` which is done by the first part  `\e]0;pi@igor: ~\a`.

The comment by [dave_thompson_085](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2868801/dave-thompson-085) reports that this is an xterm sequence:

> This is an xterm defined sequence, not ANSI or DEC. See https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Operating-System-Commands (and the top of the page where OSC is explained as ESC ] or \x9D).